# Worker/Background Thread "smothers" UI thread Android- Why?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

So when running the following method in doInBackground() inside of AsyncTask derived class:

```
void waitUntilButtonClicked(){
            while(true){
            synchronized (buttonClicked){
                if(buttonClicked) return;
                                        }
                try{Thread.sleep(1);} catch(InterruptedException e){};

                             }
```

without the very last line of code which makes the background thread sleep for 1 ms, the User Interface doesn't work (there is an EditText widget which when tapped on doesn't respond at all). I should mention that when waitUntilButtonClicked() runs the UI thread doesn't run anything (or rather not any of my code).

My problem is that I HAD to add the last line for everything to work. 
I thought that a background thread cannot block the UI thread unless there is a huge error on the programmer's part.
 Why does it happen? And yes I've figured out a 'way' to overcome that, is my solution a common method of doing that? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does it happen?

You are tying up the CPU in [a busy spin loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25067059/what-is-busy-spin-in-a-multi-threaded-environment), starving everything else of CPU cycles.

> And yes I've figured out a 'way' to overcome that, is my solution a common method of doing that?

No, as [sleeping to make a busy spin loop less busy generally is considered to be poor form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096794/is-sleep-evil).

> Is there a better way?

Let's assume, given your code, that you have a `Button`, and when the `Button` is clicked, you want to do work in a background thread.

If that is the case, you could:

- Only fork the thread once the `Button` is clicked, in the `onClick()` for the `Button`
- Maintain a thread pool (e.g., [`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor())), and post a job to that thread pool in the `onClick()` for the `Button`
- Use `startService()` to kick off an `IntentService` in the `onClick()` for the `Button`, where the `IntentService` does the work in `onHandleIntent()` (which is called on a background thread)
- Use a `HandlerThread` and `post()` events to it from `onClick()` for the `Button`
- Use mid-level blocking mechanisms, like `CountDownLatch` or `Semaphore`, where you trigger your background thread that way instead of via the `boolean`
- Use seriously low-level blocking mechanisms, like `Object#wait()`

Probably there are other options as well, but those six would be a good starting point. All of these cases use OS-level blocking primitives to mark a thread as suspended until necessary, rather than your approach of waking up the thread unnecessarily every millisecond.

Comment: First of all nice answer I can, and will, take a lot from it. However there is just one point which I did ask, is important and you have missed: even though that loop is a bad form, why does it starve the other (UI) thread?! It confuses me since..even if the OS doesn't prioritize the main thread, shouldn't it switch between the different threads,especially on interrupts such as the user touching the EditText widget?

Comment: @YoniKeren: "even if the OS doesn't prioritize the main thread" -- AFAIK, the main application thread is normal priority. Your job when creating a background thread is to reduce its priority, which helps a bit but is no performance cure-all. "shouldn't it switch between the different threads,especially on interrupts such as the user touching the EditText widget?" -- it is, though there seems to be some event loss when the main application thread is sluggish to process events.

Comment: @YoniKeren: All that being said, I'm no expert on enough of Android's implementation to give you a complete explanation. However, this is not an Android-specific problem; this sort of thing has been an issue since the invention of threads. Hence, I tend not to worry about the details. :-)